# Late 80s book with a militaristic space faring civilization where protagonist is an alien entity possessing a commander of the civilization

Tags: story-identification, books, space, space-combat

Trying to find the name/author of a book I've read a while ago. As far as I recall, this was a single book published in the late 80s (maybe 1987). Published in English. I want to say the cover had a white border with a picture of a space ship/battle cruiser inset within the border, but this detail is not reliable. I've looked at sources (Wikipedia, Goodreads) for books published around this timeframe, but they either didn't provide enough detail for me to connect the dots or didn't seem to be what I was remembering.

Setting is in space with a civilization/empire known for its militaristic conquest. The protagonist is an alien/cosmic entity who possesses the body of a ruthless/brutal commander just prior to his armada engaging an enemy in battle. I believe the entity refers to it as a "game" they play from time to time.

During this initial battle the entity/commander asks the chief engineer to develop a new weapon to turn the tide for them. I believe it was a space mine of some sort. As a result of the battle, a daughter of the opposing commander is taken as a companion to the entity (IIRC, to ensure no further hostilities). She stays with him throughout the story. The new weapon/space mines make an appearance later in the story as well.

Comment: Hi there! :) that's some info already, but maybe you could take a look at [these guidelines for story-ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, any recollection what the cover looked like? Was it written in English, was it a translation? Stuff like that, to increase the chances of a successful ID. In the meantime, don't hesitate to take the [tour]!

Comment: Added in a bit more detail, but I feel sketchy about the book cover. I read a number of scifi books and may be confusing it with another book from that same time. I'm not even sure if the book was hard or soft cover, though I do recall getting it from the local library.